# Parent component not hides in Angular router

Tags: angular, typescript, router, angular-router, angular-load-children

I have an appComponent in which i display a toolbar, footer and the main content. This main content uses the `router-outlet` directive. It's something like this

```
<div class="h-100">
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
    <div class="container h-100">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the toolbar I have a menu with some items. For example

```
<button [routerLink]="['/list']" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}">List</button>
```

When I click on the button I can show the content of that page (because of the router-outlet). I can now show a table with some content and it works fine. Now, I need to click on a row and show the detail of the row itself. To do that I'm just doing something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['detail/',row.id]">{{value}}</a>
```

and in the same page of this table (I am using `ngx-datatable`) I have another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. In this way I can now show another component at the url ".../detail/0" for example. This is called `DetailComponent`. What's the problem? Everything works well expect for the parent component (the table) that still stays there. When I click a row, The table not disappears but stays there and just below it, the child component appears. This is my `routes` by the way

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'list', 
    component: ListComponent, 
    canActivate : [AuthguardService], 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent, canActivate : [AuthguardService],
        data: {
          breadcrumb: ''
        }
      }
     ],
     data: {
      breadcrumb: 'List'
    } 
  },{
    path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried also to remove `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` from the ListComponent but if I do that, the child component doesn't show

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-n2uzis?file=app/views/details/detail.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior with the current route setup.

In order to fix it, there should be a wrapper component instead of the ListComponent, and list component should also be a child of it like DetailComponent.

Components listed as children under a route do not make the parent component to disappear, parent will be the anchor and it's children will be rendered to where you place the router-outlet in the parent component.

Comment: And so, the parent component of ListComponent and DetailComponent could just contain the <router-outlet></router-outlet>? Or what?

Comment: Yes exactly, or some simple layout to place them properly on screen.

Comment: In I create a parent component with only <router-outlet></router-outlet> I can't see anything

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz MRE, I can help you with the implementation.

Comment: Ok I'm going to create a stackblitz in a moment

Comment: So, that's exactly my problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-n2uzis?file=app/views/details/detail.component.ts

Comment: Click on "list" and then the id. What I would is that the table disappear when I click the id. When I go back with the browser navigation the table should be visible again

Comment: Here, I've implemented the above mentioned approach https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-xpfkpr? , I can answer if you have any questions.

Comment: Basically, I've added a parent component wrapping your catalog list and details, and added route config to redirect to the list view by default, also updated some of the routerLinks to reflect the changes.

Comment: Yeah it's working fine!! Thanks! Now I get it! Just one question, do you think it would be possibile to skip the "catalog" part of the url? I mean, something like "../list/" and then "../list/detail/1" using this kind of structure of course.

Comment: It is possible but depends on the use case, if you leave the parent route blank like “” and adjust other things to be adjacent it should be fine.